# How to access external drive in melody music player / flatpak app

Tags: linux, permissions, flatpak

I am on Ubuntu 18.10 and have installed the music player [Melody](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.artemanufrij.playmymusic). I can install this flatpak and run the app, but when I want to link my music folder on my **external USB drive** to the library, no folders under `/media` are showing up.

## How to make Melody have access permissions to external drives?

*edit:* See similar question on ask ubunt: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086529/how-to-give-a-flatpak-app-access-to-a-directory

Comment: thx for your constructive feedback @jww. I think ask ubuntu could be a better frame. Will move question there and delete this one.

Answer (score 3):

Found out, that it is possible to override *filesystem permissions* via terminal command:

`sudo flatpak override --filesystem=host com.github.artemanufrij.playmymusic`

After restarting the app, the folders are showing up as expected and Melody can import/play the files.

Source: http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions-reference.html?highlight=override#filesystem-permissions

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add, if you're using [flatseal](https://github.com/tchx84/flatseal), which is a permission utility for flatpak, select you app, and just scroll down on the right pane until you find **FIle System**, and toggle **All system files**:
[image: flatseal toggel file system]